# Kerberos authentication fails with forced password change

Tags: kerberos

I have configured PAM authentication to use Kerberos and can authenticate correctly with my principals using their Kerberos credentials.

I ran into trouble when I tried to create a principal with an expired password:

```
kadmin: addprinc +needchange test_principal
```

When I tried logging in (either from a VT or the graphical greeter), after correctly entering the password, I got the expected message that the password has expired and the system prompted me to create a new one. After I had done that, authentication failed with this error in the `kdc.log`:

```
krb5kdc[...](info): TGS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.0.200: NO PREAUTH: authtime 0, test_principal@MY.REALM for host/server.my.realm@MY.REALM, Generic error (see e-text)
```

and the following (not so surprising) error in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
pam_krb5(gdm3:auth): (user test_principal) credential verfication failed: KDC returned error string: NO PREAUTH
```

**Some notes**

- Listing the principal's attributes (via `getprinc` in `kadmin.local`) shows 0 failed log in attempts
- If I create the account without the `+needchange` flag, I am able to authenticate correctly.
- If I add the `+needchange` flag (via `modprinc` in `kadmin.local`) after the user has successfully authenticated once, I get the expected behavior; namely, the user is prompted to change their password and then their authentication succeeds.
- This principal has no equivalent entry in `/etc/passwd` but is backed up by an LDAP entry.
- As suggested elsewhere, I tried creating my principal like this:

  ```
  kadmin: addprinc -requires_preauth +needchange test_principal
  ```

  This made no difference.

**My use case**

I'm migrating from an old NIS system and I want to offer continuity to my users. I would like to have them enter their old passwords but then be forced to change them to conform to stricter password policy rules I intend to enforce through Kerberos.

I am running MIT Kerberos V on Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer and it's a very strange one!

I used the `getprinc` command within `kadmin` to obtain the attributes of both the problem principal and a principal that was created without `+needchange` and that was authenticating correctly.

The difference was that the principal authenticating correctly had the `REQUIRES_PRE_AUTH` attribute set while the problem principal didn't have it, so the solution is to create the principal this way:

```
kadmin: addprinc +needchange +requires_preauth test_principal
```